# Create instance of UIView subclass programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I've create a subclass of UIView which just has drawRect overridden. For simplicity's sake I am not creating a UIView in Interface Builder to represent what will be my subclass, but am rather wanting to just create an instance of it in my UIViewController code.

I've tried the following:

```
canvasView = CanvasView(frame: view.bounds)
canvasView.dataSource = self
```

As well as:

```
canvasView = UIView(frame: view.bounds) as! CanvasView
canvasView.dataSource = self
```

But for both of them I receive the error..

> Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'dataSource'

What is the proper way of going about this? Do I *need* to create a UIView in IB? It is embedded within a UIScrollView, which I am also creating programmatically and is working well, so I would really prefer to not have to, if possible.

Comment: How do you declare your `canvasView`? Did you do `var canvasView: UIView`?

Comment: I don't know your your exact thinking about this,but it clearly says the `CanvasView` class doesn't have a `dataSource` property. So tell us - does it or not?

Comment: CanvasView does have it. The error I am getting is that UIView doesn't have a dataSource property, which is what is making me question whether I am creating an instance of it correctly. What I am doing looks correct then?

Comment: Is it then the `dataSource` property designated as `private`? Sorry about that, but I will trust the compiler - in this case - as it's so extremely simple , it would be VERY strange if the swift compiler was wrong...

Comment: I'm not declaring it as private. Just tried putting public in front of the property for good measure and received "Declaring a public var for an internal class" warning.

I have a feeling there is probably something very silly I am just missing.

Comment: How is `canvasView` declared? ie. edit your question to show `var canvasView...`

Comment: Give more info about your properties and protocol datasource that you are trying to set

Comment: Yep. Something silly. People suggesting canvasView declaration was off were correct. It was overriding whatever type it was when I was creating the instance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is fine except for the fact that a UIView does not have a datasource.

More information about what you want to achieve would be helpful here.

Since I don't have a definition of your CanvasView it's hard to know what is going wrong. Below is something I put together in a playground that shows you one way you can set up a dataSource for your class.

```
import UIKit

protocol DataSourceProtocol {
    var data: Any { get set }
}

class DataSource: DataSourceProtocol {
    var data: Any

    init(data: Any) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

class ViewWithDataSource: UIView {
    var dataSource: DataSourceProtocol?
}

let dataSource = DataSource(data: "Some Data")
let myView = ViewWithDataSource(frame: CGRectZero)
myView.dataSource = dataSource
```

Edit: Edited out some incorrect statements/assumptions

Comment: I've declared both a delegate and dataSource on my class, but admittedly still being green to iOS I'm just following what I've seen other built-in views doing. I'll probably switch over to just a delegate in that case then.

Comment: Can you please post for us the definition of the CanvasView?

Comment: @AdamCampbell `UITableView` has data source, `UICollectionView` has a datasource; there is no reason views can't have data sources.  A datasource is really just another delegate pattern; it may be that it makes sense to separate the functionality of the delegate (that responds to events in the control) and the data source (that supplies data to the control)

Comment: @Paulw11 You are absolutely correct. Answer updated. Will double check myself before I answer on a Monday morning next time.